# PHP Code Displaying as Plain Text After First Key in Associative Array

Tags: php, wamp

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Zodiac Gallery</title>
</head>
<body>
<?
$Zodiac = array( 
  "monkey.jpg" => "monkey",
  "rooster.jpg" => "rooster",
  "dog.jpg" => "dog",
  "pig.jpg" => "pig", 
  "rat.jpg" => "rat", 
  "ox.jpg" => "ox", 
  "tiger.jpg" => "tiger", 
  "rabbit.jpg" => "rabbit", 
  "dragon.jpg" => "dragon", 
  "snake.jpg" => "snake", 
  "horse.jpg" => "horse", 
  "goat.jpg" => "goat"
);
foreach ( $Zodiac as $image => $caption ) {
  $size = getimagesize("images/$image");
  DEBUGGING print_r($size);
  echo '<a href="images/'.$image.'"><img src="images/'.$image.'" alt="'.$caption.'" height="75" width="75"></a>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The purpose of this is to create a small thumbnail gallery such that when the thumbnails are clicked, they display the larger images.

I'm having an issue with the output and I have no idea why. I would appreciate it, if I could get some help.

The file does have a .php extension, and I'm using WAMP.

[This is the output I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jALCj.png).

**Edit: Solved thanks to chris85. Couldn't use short tags for some reason.**

Comment: You don't have short tags enabled? Change `<?` to `<?php`.

Comment: I've tried that. Doesn't help anything.

Comment: You have other PHP pages working?

Comment: Other PHP pages work fine. Its this specific page with the error.

Comment: Did you enable short tags or add the `<?php`?

Comment: Worked after adding the <?php. Didn't matter in any of the code I did before. Not sure why it matters now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of *borrowed code* that uses `short_tags` you can turn them on by changing

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

to

```
short_open_tag = On
```

in the `php.ini` file. Use the wampmanager menus to edit the correct `php.ini` file.

```
wampmanager->PHP->php.ini
```

will open the file in your editor.